# i use xcode 9 , how to special key double quote insert nsarray data?

Tags: ios, xcode, nsarray, double-quotes

For example

```
NSArray *special_keys = @[@"!",@"@", ..... , @":", @"**"**"];
```

But this does not store the value as I intended.

I want to know how to store double quotes in `NSArray`.

Comment: do you want to store double quote ("") in `NSArray ` right ?

Comment: what is your intended output?

Comment: try this @"\*\*\"\*\*"

Answer (score 0):

You can do like,

```
NSArray *specialKeys = @[@"""", @"**\"**"];

NSLog(@"special keys : %@",specialKeys);
```

and the result is,

```
special keys : (
"",
"**\"**"
)
```

Comment: oh; ** ** is bold code  

*specialKeys = @[@"\""]; 

Is this all right?

Comment: sorry I am not getting your comment!

Comment: what you want to achieve exactly ?

Comment: I want to have only double quotes in nsarray.

@"""

Comment: one time double quote  `(")` or two time `("")`  ?

Comment: one time double quote (")

Comment: Is it impossible?